# Excel search value in multiple rows and multiple columns and return results in a range

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I have the following data:

```
Cable type      Route 1      Route 2     Results row                                       Search route for cables
ΝΥΥ-J 4x2,5     7                        ΝΥΥ-J 4x2,5 ΝΥΥ-J 5x2,5 ΝΥΥ-J 3x1,5               7
ΝΥΥ-J 5x2,5     7
ΝΥΥ-J 4x2,5     4            3
                             7
ΝΥΥ-J 3x1,5     6            7
```

I want a formula to be able to search for the value 7 in both "Route 1" and "Route 2" columns and if match is found, I want it to add in the results range the text from the corresponding "Cable type" text of the row that the match occured.
For example, if I search for the value 7 I need it to return 3 texts due to the 3 matches found(2 from the 1st column and 1 from the second).

I have the following formula but does what I want only for 1 column.

```
=IFERROR(INDEX($A$2:$A$5;AGGREGATE(15;3;($B$2:$B$5=$I$2)/($B$2:$B$5=$I$2)*(ROW($A$2:$A$5)-ROW($A$1));COLUMNS($J$1:J4)));"")
```

**Note:** The same number can not exist in both "Route 1" and "Route 2"columns in the same row.
Excel version 2013

**Edit**: I stumbled on a problem. If I search for the number 7 and there is indeed a match in the Route columns but in the "Cable type" column there is nothing I need it not to return a 0 but skip the row as if like there was no match with the "Route" columns. I edited the data in the example above.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Do your expression twice, once for each column and concatenate the results, you may need to use iferror() if nothing is found.

Comment: Thing is that I may have up to 10 columns of "Routes", the formula would be to lengthy(if there is no other more elegant solution I may end up doing that). And indeed I would preffer the results to be shown concatinated in one single cell instead of multiple(range) like was my original thought.

Answer (score 2):

**A. For Excel 2019 or Office 365**

In "Result `F2` enter array (Ctrl+Shift+Enter) formula :

```
=TEXTJOIN(", ",,IF(B2:B5=I2,A2:A5,""),IF(C2:C5=I2,A2:A5,""))
```

[image]

**B. For Excel 2016 or below version, you need using helper column to concatenate the results.**

1] In "Helper 1" `D2`, formula copied down :

```
=IF(B2=I$2,A2,"")&IFERROR("@"&INDEX(D3:D$100,MATCH(I$2,B3:B$100,0)),"")
```

2] In "Helper 2" `E2`, formula copied down :

```
=IF(C2=I$2,A2,"")&IFERROR("@"&INDEX(E3:E$100,MATCH(I$2,C3:C$100,0)),"")
```

3] In "Result" `F2`, enter formula :

```
=SUBSTITUTE(MID(D2&E2,2,99),"@",", ")
```

[image]

Remark : To change the above formula "Comma" to "Semi-colon" in meet with your country setting.

Comment: I am sorry, I ommited to mention my Excel version, I have the 2013 therefore I don't have the TEXTJOINT function.

Comment: @Vangde Please see my post new edit in adding new formula for your Excel 2013 version

Comment: Elcellent, I need to add a few more helper columns because i have more Route columns in reality but now its easy. Thank you very much @bosco_yip

Answer (score 0):

If you have Excel 2013, you could do:

```
=LEFT(CONCAT(IF(B2:B5=I2,A2:A5&",",""),IF(C2:C5=I2,A2:A5&",","")),LEN(CONCAT(IF(B2:B5=I2,A2:A5&",",""),IF(C2:C5=I2,A2:A5&",","")))-1)
```

It's not so nice because it calcs the strings twice, but if your column A values are of variable size, it makes it easier to manage.

So one more approach:

```
=LEFT(CONCAT(IF(B2:B5=I2,A2:A5&",",""),IF(C2:C5=I2,A2:A5&",","")),SUM(IF(B2:B5=I2,LEN(A2:A5&","),0)+IF(C2:C5=I2,LEN(A2:A5&","),0))-1)
```

It may compute faster.

Comment: CONCAT function is only available on Excel 2019 or Office 365, Excel 2013 don't have this function